# Visual Studio - memory leak detection - breakpoint does not work & unidentified leaks

Tags: c++, memory-leaks, visual-studio-2013

I want to test programs for memory leaks in C++ Visual Studio memory leak detection. On some leaks, there is nice path to the source and line number in the Debug console. But on some leaks there is only memory address. Some I was able to identify in my code, but some not. On some applications it is e.g. 12 bytes and on some more.

I tried the simplest possible Unit test, with the following method. And even this throws 4-byte leak.

Cpp file:

```
TEST_METHOD(TestMemoryLeakDetection){
 _CrtDumpMemoryLeaks();
}
```

stdafx.h, which is included in all files here:

```
#pragma once
#include "targetver.h"
#define WIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN             // Exclude rarely-used stuff from Windows headers

// http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e5ewb1h3(v=vs.71).aspx
#define _CRTDBG_MAP_ALLOC
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <crtdbg.h>
#ifdef _DEBUG
    #ifndef DBG_NEW
        #define DBG_NEW new ( _NORMAL_BLOCK , __FILE__ , __LINE__ )
        #define new DBG_NEW
    #endif
#endif  // _DEBUG
```

The detect output during the debug shows this:

```
Detected memory leaks!
Dumping objects ->
{147} normal block at 0x069A9EA0, 4 bytes long.
 Data: <t  ]> 74 A8 95 5D 
Object dump complete.
```

I've tried also this, but it does nothing:

```
TEST_METHOD(TestMemoryLeakDetectionFour){
 _CrtSetDbgFlag(_CRTDBG_ALLOC_MEM_DF | _CRTDBG_LEAK_CHECK_DF );
 _CrtSetBreakAlloc(147);
 _CrtSetBreakAlloc(146);
}
```

I am using Visual Studio 2013 and Visual C++ ~ Native Unit Test Project. 
Note that in bigger projects, I experience more and more similar small 4-byte leaks (and I am unable to determine where are they from).

Thanks for any ideas. 
Jarda

Comment: Perhaps visual leak detector https://vld.codeplex.com/ might help

Comment: Compare what you get with output made by Deleaker (it's free for 14 days). Sometimes stack trace (I am not sure that this is your case!) might be corrupted and thus no way to get source of leak. That is why it's useful to compare results produced by different tools.